# What Non-Literals May Be Used When Declaring a VBA Constant?

Tags: r, excel, vba, constants, literals

## Background

I am using an R script to generate VBA code. To be fully dynamic, the R script must infer its parameters from numeric `Const`ants in an existing VBA module.

Since the set of legal names for R variables is a superset of those for VBA variables, and since the numeric operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, etc.) are generally synonymous, it is easy enough to model the VBA constants...

```vb
Const NUM_1 As Long = 1 + 2
Const NUM_2 As Long = 10 * NUM_1
' ...
Const NUM_N As Long = NUM_2 / 6
```

...in a compartmentalized R environment like `vba_env`...

```r
# The model environment.
vba_env <- new.env(parent = baseenv())


# Extract the names and expressions from the declarations.
name_1 <- "NUM_1"; expr_1 <- "1 + 4"
name_2 <- "NUM_2"; expr_2 <- "10 * NUM_1"
# ...
name_n <- "NUM_N"; expr_n <- "NUM_2 / 5"


# Model these constants: evaluate them in and bind them to the model environment.
assign(x = name_1, envir = vba_env, value = eval(
  expr = parse(text = expr_1),
  envir = vba_env
))
assign(x = name_2, envir = vba_env, value = eval(
  expr = parse(text = expr_2),
  envir = vba_env
))
# ...
assign(x = name_n, envir = vba_env, value = eval(
  expr = parse(text = expr_n),
  envir = vba_env
))
```

...and so infer the relevant values.

```r
as.list(vba_env)
#> $NUM_1
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $NUM_2
#> [1] 50
#> 
#> $NUM_N
#> [1] 10
```

### Note

Don't worry about my R workflow.  I have extensibly automated this process with regex extractors and various iterators.  This manual approach is merely for visual clarity.

## Problem

I recently realized that certain [intrinsic constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-constants) are available for `Const`ant declarations.

```vb
Const STR_V As String = VBA.Constants.vbTab & " "
Const NUM_W As String = 1 + VBA.VbVarType.vbLong
```

Worse yet, it seems these constants may (or may not) be [qualified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-constants#qualifying-constants-by-library-reference) with any sequence of library references:

```vb
Const NUM_X As String = 1 + VBA.vbLong
Const NUM_Y As String = 1 + VbVarType.vbLong
Const NUM_Z As String = 1 + vbLong
```

## Solution

The solution is naturally to build a contextual environment for the model:

```r
# Assemble the context...
cxt_list <- list(
  VBA.VbVarType.vbLong = 3,
  VBA.vbLong = 3,
  VbVarType.vbLong = 3,
  vbLong = 3
  
  # ...
)

# ...as an environment.
cxt_env <- list2env(cxt_list, parent = baseenv())


# The model environment, with access to the context environment.
vba_env <- new.env(parent = cxt_env)


# Extract a name and a (non-literal) expression.
name_x <- "NUM_X"; expr_x <- "1 + VBA.vbLong"


# Model this constants: evaluate it in and bind it to the model environment.
assign(x = name_x, envir = vba_env, value = eval(
  expr = parse(text = expr_x),
  envir = vba_env
))
```

When evaluating the expression `1 + VBA.vbLong`, the model (`vba_env`) will default to the context (`cxt_env`) as a namespace, to retrieve the value for `VBA.vbLong`:

```r
as.list(vba_env)
#> $NUM_X
#> [1] 4
```

## Questions

1. **What all non-literals, built into VBA, may be validly used in `Const`ant declarations?**  Such non-literals may indeed be intrinsic constants (`vbTab`, `xlDialogBorder`, etc.), or they may be anything else besides a simple operation on literals and prior constants (`1 + 2`, `10 * NUM_1`, etc.).
2. **What are the rules for qualifying such non-literals (like intrinsic constants)?**  Consider an intrinsic constant `xxConst`, nested under the categories (`Cat_1`, `Cat_2`, `Cat_3`), in some library `LibX`.  Which **`Code`** samples below would serve as a valid qualification?

| Qualification | Code |
| --- | --- |
| None | `xxConst` |
| Full | `LibX.Cat_1.Cat_2.Cat_3.xxConst` |
| Only Library | `LibX. xxConst` |
| No Library | `Cat_1.Cat_2.Cat_3.xxConst` |
| Prefix | `LibX.Cat_1. xxConst` |
| Suffix | `Cat_2.Cat_3.xxConst` |
| Inner | `Cat_1.Cat_2. xxConst` |
| Disjoint | `LibX. Cat_2. xxConst` |

Comment: You could do no worse that by directing this question to the Rubberduck team.

Comment: @freeflow Thanks for the advice...but I'm a bit confused by your phrasing: _"You could do **no** worse..."_.  Are you recommending that I **do** reach out to Rubberduck, or are you saying I should **not**?

Comment: Yes.  Reach out to them.  Rubberduck is a free and fantastic addin for VBA/VB6 that does static analysis of VBA code.  Try installing and then looking at the code inspections.  To do that thier code must parse VBA so there may be a way for you to hook into that to get the info you need.  You never know what opportunities thier API's may offer to you.